# difference between async array.map() and async npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

[Context]
I had a loop here, that I will have 760000 interations, so I'm trying to optimize it.

[Question]
In my loop, i'm using a async `array.map()` function

```
cells.map(async (cell) => {
        if (cell[0] === '!') continue;
        [...]//so much code here
        return someObj;
}
```

I saw the [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) package but I don't know what is faster, an "async map" function or the "async" package?

Please, if you can, explain the way one is faster then other.

Comment: It's like apples and bananas.

Comment: I would assume that browser built-in features would always be faster than a package to extend those features.

Comment: Pretty much the only way to know if anything is "faster" than another is to performance test it with the specific requirements that you want to load it with. Anything other than that is a guess at best or wild speculation at worst

Comment: Looking at your example code, making a map async makes little sense. map is CPU bound not IO bound so making it async is pointless.. the examples in that NPM package all include some IO operations `doSomeIO(item, callback);`, this makes sense. But that means that the NPM map and the standard map are not a like for like swap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Async code

Have you heard about [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)? If you consider that your mapping would take too long and you want to execute the following code that doesn't need the result of that array, i.e. independent code, then you can wrap it using a promise to change the execution flow.

```
const heavyMapping = arr => Promise.resolve(
    arr.map(cell => {
        if (cell[0] === '!') continue;
        [...]//so much code here
        return someObj;
    })
);

//Call the function.
heavyMapping(arr).then((result) => processResult(result));
//Rest of your program
foo();
bar();
```

So the execution would be something like: `heavyMapping -> foo -> bar ... -> processResult`. If you run your code without asynchronous code, it would be `heavyMapping -> ... -> processResult -> foo -> bar`. Note that if you are using asynchronous code, it doesn't mean that your code will be executed in parallel, since this is concurrent programming and parallelism it's a particular case of concurrency in which you have enough hardware to do both tasks at the same time. Read more about that: https://medium.com/@deepshig/concurrency-vs-parallelism-4a99abe9efb8. Anyway, if you don't want to block the execution of `foo` and `bar` you can use a promise or `aync/await` to face this issue.

### Map

I'd recommend you to use `forEach` instead of `map` in this particular case or the usage of `filter` and `map` chained. Why? Let me explain it:

1. `Map` method is used when you want to transform your original data obtaining the result in a **new** array. For instance, let say that you have an array named `people` containing objects with the following format: `{name: 'X', lastName: 'Y', age: 23 }` and you want to get the concatenation of `name` and `lastName` as a `fullName` attribute, then you could use `map` as follows: `` people.map(person => { fullName: `${name} ${lastName}` }); ``.
2. On the other hand, let's suppose you want to filter your data with the people that have at least 18 years old. You could use `filter` for that: `people.filter(person => person.age > 18);`.

In your particular case, you could use those methods chained as follows:

```
arr
.filter(cell => cell[0] ===  '!')
.map(/*so much code here*/);
```

Please note that if your block of code -*so much code here*- is not about data transformation I'd encourage you to use `forEach` chained to `filter` instead of `map`.

Sorry if I didn't understand your question, but thats what I've interpreted about it. Happy coding.

PS: if you don't know about `` `${expression}` ``, it is called [template string](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings).